# C stat() ignoring files

Tags: c, stat

I'm having an issue with the stat function in C. My application must list all files in two directories (2nd directory not implemented yet). When dir1 is set to "." for current directory it lists all files. If I change it to the required directory it will only list one file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

main ()
{
    DIR *dir1;
    DIR *dir2;
    dir1 = opendir ("/home/tom/Documents/Uni/Dropbox/OS/C/1/");
    dir2 = opendir ("/home/tom/Documents/Uni/Dropbox/OS/C/2/");
    struct dirent *ent;
    struct stat fileStat;

    if (dir1 != NULL) 
    {
        /* while there are files to read in the directory */
        while ((ent = readdir (dir1)) != NULL) 
        {
        /*printf ("In 1\n"); <--debugging--> */
        if (stat(ent->d_name,&fileStat) == 0)
        {
            /* ignores . and .. and hidden files */
            /* printf ("In 2\n"); <--debugging--> */
            if(ent->d_name[0] != '.')
            {
                /* printf ("In 3\n"); <--debugging--> */
                printf ("\n");
                printf ("File: %s\n", ent->d_name);
                printf ("File size: %d\n", fileStat.st_size);
                printf ("-----------------------------------\n");
            }
        }
    }
    /* close the 1st directory */
    closedir (dir1);
    /* close the 2nd directory */
    closedir (dir2);
    }
    else 
    {
        /* prints an error if the  directory can not be opened */
        perror ("");
    } 
}
```

The result of running the program is below:

```
tom@x60deb:~/Documents/Uni/Dropbox/OS/C$ ./ffffuuuuuu 

File: ffffuuuuuu.c
File size: 1045
-----------------------------------
```

This is the result of ls in the directory it is reading:

```
tom@x60deb:~/Documents/Uni/Dropbox/OS/C/1$ ls -l
total 36
-rw-r--r-- 1 tom tom 356 Dec 12 23:36 cwTest2.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 tom tom 322 Dec 12 23:36 cwTest.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 tom tom 627 Dec 12 23:36 ffffuuuuuu.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 tom tom   6 Dec 12 23:32 file
-rw-r--r-- 1 tom tom   6 Dec 12 23:32 file2
-rw-r--r-- 1 tom tom   6 Dec 12 23:45 file2.file
-rw-r--r-- 1 tom tom  15 Dec 12 23:33 file3
-rw-r--r-- 1 tom tom  15 Dec 12 23:45 file3.file
-rw-r--r-- 1 tom tom   6 Dec 12 23:45 file.file
```

Thanks in advance,
Tom.

Comment: what is your current directory? the entries are relative to "/home/tom/Documents/Uni/Dropbox/OS/C/1/" (you should give stat() the full pathname) ALSO: there are more entries than "." and ".." that start with ".".

Comment: Output the error of stat, and you'll know what the problem is.

Comment: @wildplasser I am running it in /home/tom/Documents/Uni/Dropbox/OS

Comment: @Beginner I'm not getting any errors that I am aware of. It just seems to be skipping some files.

Comment: I think the point of the comments is to determine why you're skipping files.  Does the readdir() return NULL prematurely?  At what point?  Is stat() failing such that you silently skip that code block?  Reporting when failures happen will go a long way toward solving your problem.

Comment: I have found that running the program from the actual directory lists all of the files so I'm guessing it's to do with the path defined in the variable dir1?

Comment: Fixed it. Just some plain old path magic. Untested.

Comment: That unaligned while loop braces makes my head hurt.  Formatting is important...

Comment: That's fixed. Working perfectly now. Thanks very much.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan The loop is only unaligned because it messed up when I copied it in. It is properly formatted in my actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main (void)
{
    char * dirname = "/home/tom/Documents/Uni/Dropbox/OS/C/1/" ;
    DIR *dir1;
    char path[11111];
    size_t len;
    struct dirent *ent;
    struct stat fileStat;

    dir1 = opendir (dirname);
    len = strlen ( dirname);
    memcpy(path, dirname, len+1);

    struct dirent *ent;
    struct stat fileStat;

    if (dir1 != NULL) 
    {
        /* while there are files to read in the directory */
        while ((ent = readdir (dir1)) != NULL) 
        {
        /*printf ("In 1\n"); <--debugging--> */
        strcpy(path+len, ent->d_name);
        if (stat( path,&fileStat) == 0)
        {
            /* ignores . and .. and hidden files */
            /* printf ("In 2\n"); <--debugging--> */
            if(ent->d_name[0] != '.')
            {
                /* printf ("In 3\n"); <--debugging--> */
                printf ("\n");
                printf ("File: %s\n", ent->d_name);
                printf ("File size: %d\n", fileStat.st_size);
                printf ("-----------------------------------\n");
            }
        }
    }
    /* close the 1st directory */
    closedir (dir1);
    }
    else 
    {
        /* prints an error if the  directory can not be opened */
        perror ("");
    }
return 0; 
}
```

UPDATE because some people cannot read, I'll add my original comment here:

what is your current directory? the entries are relative to "/home/tom/Documents/Uni/Dropbox/OS/C/1/" (you should give stat() the full pathname) ALSO: there are more entries than "." and ".." that start with ".".

Comment: There is no text or anything saying what you did here for your solution.  What did you do?

Comment: I added it in the comments, under the OP. diff is your friend. BTW: I updated.

Comment: Diff as in a local app that I cut and paste code into, or something on this website I am not aware of?  BTW, -1 is not me.

Comment: Anyone who spends a few minutes reading should be able to spot the differences. Otherwise he/she could scrape the content, and run diff manually.

Comment: You should use `PATH_MAX` (from limits.h) rather than 11111 for the size of your path array.

Comment: I know. But since we are doing homework here, it must be hidden behind a magic constant. Besides: IIRC PATH_MAX is dictated as 4096-1 by posix, so I feel safe ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the name to `stat()` either as an absolute path name or as the name relative to the current directory.

If your scanner is changing directory then (a) you're a braver man than I am, and (b) you can use the short names, but (c) you have to worry about how to get back to where you started.

If you have POSIX 2008, you may be able to use the `*at()` variants of the system calls to simplify life; but I'm not sure how many (if any) systems support those calls yet.