# C - size of a file from an absolute path

Tags: c, stat

**QUESTION: Is there a means to obtain a file's size as `off_t` with an *absolute* file path when the file path *relative* to the current working directory is not known**

This may well be marked as a duplicate but I believe it sufficiently varys from questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482659/c-stat-ignoring-files) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165100/how-to-find-the-size-of-a-file-in-a-different-relative-directory-using-stat-in) as I do not wish to use a relative path.

Like many folk -it appears- I fell into the trap of assuming that when looking to obtain file information `stat()` used *absolute* rather than *relative* (to the current working directory) pathnames. I have an absolute path to a file that I need to identify the size of as `off_t`. The second issue I discovered was that absolute pathnames -aside from pointing in the wrong place- may also exceed `PATH_MAX` from `limits.h`?.

The function below which was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236/how-do-you-determine-the-size-of-a-file-in-c) offers a means to obtain an `off_t` with a relative path. BUT this will obviously return `No such file or directory` via errno with an absolute path because it uses `stat()`.

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

off_t fsize(const char *filename) {
    struct stat st;

    if (stat(filename, &st) == 0)
        return st.st_size;

    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot determine size of %s: %s\n",
            filename, strerror(errno));

    return -1;
}
```

Because I know someone will ask; I was advised that `chdir()` is neither thread safe nor good practice; that I should avoid changing the current working directory. I was also advised to steer clear of `fseek()` but there was no rationale given as to why..

Comment: And... What are you asking? `stat()` does work with absolute paths!

Comment: The current directory you set with `chdir()` is like a global variable, shared between threads and affect the system calls for all threads that work with pathnames. For this reason I agree that you should only initialize it once at program startup before spawning threads. `fseek()`: I agree that you shouldn't use it when isn't necessary (and it is rarely reasonable to use it). Not all kind of streams support seeking! By not using seek operation your stream-user code becomes more generalized and can be used with a lot more kinds of streams. For example a socket is a non-seekable stream.

Comment: Ahh...I am most definately confused.

Comment: the above function provides me with the errno error `No such file or directory` when accessing `/home/chortle/Documents/C/foo/src` despite the file existing.

Comment: I clearly misinterpreted what was written elsewhere regarding absolute path's

Comment: The *path* is completely irrelevant. There could be two or more directory entries pointing to the same inode. (or even zero links: fstat() could give the size of a file descriptor that does not even have a directory entry)

Comment: Are you sure that's the path you're passing to stat? E.g. have you checked you don't have a newline at the end of the path or anything?

Comment: I'd recommend looking at `fstatat()`, which does absolute and relative paths, as well as removing the necessity for `chdir()`.

Comment: @immibis I hard coded as `const char*` as part of debugging `"fsize("/home/chortle/Documents/C/foo/src");`

Comment: @EOF thanks I'll take a look; I did try fstat but the `int fd` I obtained from the file stream came back `bad file descriptor`.

Comment: And the file path definitely exists? (`ls /home/chortle/Documents/C/foo/src` doesn't print an error, for example). And your program isn't running in a chroot jail or anything weird like that?

Comment: @immibis; `ls` returns it so I'm guessing it does exist, and no not chrooting or jailing

Comment: Most probably cause: a trailing space or CR in the pathname. (or for even more fun: a *backspace* )

Comment: @KemyLand thanks for correcting my understanding regarding absolute path's and to all for the quick responses. I think I'm going to have to re-look and see if it's something else messing up the call to `stat()`.

Comment: @Chortle: Say us if you have any other question :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) allows you to specify a file using it's full path name from the root directory (if the path starts with a `/`) or a relative one (otherwise, see [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html)), from your current directory.  Even if you don't know any of the names (in case yo have only an open file descriptor, and you don't know the name of this file) you have the possibility of making a `fstat(2)` system call.

Be careful with the fact that the file size can change between the `stat(2)` call you make to know the file size and whatever you could do after.  Think on opening with `O_APPEND` flag if you want to assure your write will not be interspesed with others'.

Comment: Good edit Basile, a reference to path_resolution was the best complement to complete this answer.  Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Whilst my question was poor this was the most helpful with respect to understanding `stat()` and `fstat()` was what I ended up using in the end.

Comment: @Chortle, there's another way to get the file size using `lseek(2)`, but it has the drawback that needs an open file descriptor (not a pathname as you requested in your question) so I didn't mention it.